# Is there a way to watch for file changes while developing azure functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-tasks, azure-functions-core-tools

For dotnet there is `dotnet watch run`
For node there is `nodemon`

Is there anyway to watch for file changes while developing azure functions? So far, I have to `func start` after every change in order to test it out. I haven't seen any information related to this.

Comment: I've added [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1408#issue-460450211) to the GitHub repo for azure functions core tools.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a workaround solution here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1239#issuecomment-669018902

Add this to your csproj:

```
  <Target Name="RunFunctions">
    <Exec Command="func start" />
  </Target>
```

Then you can run with watch by calling this:

```
dotnet watch msbuild /t:RunFunctions
```

NB: If you want to use some common commands, you could configure a package.json with a start script e.g.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "dotnet watch msbuild /t:RunFunctions"
  }
}
```

Then you can simply run with `yarn start`

Comment: What is the solution for this in nodejs ?

Comment: In Node you generally ensure you are using a build tool (webpack, rollup, parcel, etc.) with hot-reloading including ... search hot-reloading with your chosen framework for details, this answer is bringing that to C# as best we can.

Comment: BTW: If you have any additional command line parameters to include then add them to the csproj Exec entry (such as `--verbose` or `--cors *` for example).

You can have include difference named targets and include script for each, if you have different run modes (HTTP vs HTTPS for example).  If you need double-quotes in your command then encode them as '&quot;'.

For those wanting to configure .NET Core projects in VS, see https://dev.to/juxant/auto-refresh-with-dotnet-watch-for-asp-net-core-projects-20no.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible.

On further searching I found [hot reload](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1239#issue-437771257) is an idea for second half of calendar year 2019.

Comment: Is there a generally accepted workaround for this yet? This is still not supported apparently.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It may be worth re-opening my initial issue on github. But I admittedly haven't searched too hard since posting this. If TypeScript is on the table you can use that + webpack for hot reload during dev.

Comment: @baouss this just in (sorry if SO notified you already), but an accepted answer FYI